# Accessing properties of a custom UITableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a property, specifically a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in a (reusable) subclass of `UITableViewCell`. When a cell is selected, an `AVAsset` is fetched from a URL but I want the `UIActivityIndicatorView` to hide when the sufficient data has been fetched from the URL and the `AVAsset` is ready to use. But I don't know how to access the cell that was selected. I figured the best way was to set up a pointer to the last selected cell in a property and access it later like this.

```
@interface
@property (nonatomic, retain) customTableViewCustomCell *activeCell;
@end

@implementation
@synthesize activeCell;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // remember pointer to active cell for later
    activeCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void) updateInterface
{
    [activeCell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

But I get a compile error about incompatible pointer types because `cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` returns a `UITableViewCell` and not a `customUITableViewCell`. I need a pointer to `customUITableViewCell` so I have access to the `activtyIndicator` `IBOutlet` property.

Comment: You can try using the NSNotification Center while till the sufficient data gets downloaded & using the delegate method you can Reload your Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  activeCell = (customTableViewCustomCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: Ahh... The old typecast. Should have known.